# Custom sorting on special data column

Tags: c#

I have a data set that I'm displaying with a special column called, `4_Most_Previlent`.  It's data type is a string and has the following format, Item1-Item2-Item3-Item4.

Here would be an example of some values for this column:

```
Cl-K-Be-Li
K-Cl-He-O
Cu-Mn-Ca-Cl
Cr-Cu-Mn-Cu
Cu-Cr-Mn-Cu
Cr-Cu-Ca-S
```

I like to do a custom of items based on this column you could say the first and second elements need to be the same, but could be interchanged.  So it would be like AB|CD or BA|CD.  So in my above example the top 2 items would be sorted next to each other as they both start with the same 2 items, but they are transposed.  Also the bottom 3 would be sorted next to each other.

Any thoughts on how to do this and/or a code snippet in C# would be greatly appreciate.  Thanks!

Comment: targeting WPF, but winform's would be ok as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wrap the strings inside of a class, and then you're free to implement `IComparable` however you need.

For example:

```
class SomeRecord : IComparable<SomeRecord> {
    public SomeRecord(string line) {
        string[] fields = line.Split('-');
        Item1 = fields[0];
        Item2 = fields[1];
        Item3 = fields[2];
        Item4 = fields[3];
    }
    public string Item1 { get;set; }
    public string Item2 { get;set; }
    public string Item3 { get;set; }
    public string Item4 { get;set; }

    int IComparable<SomeRecord>.CompareTo(SomeRecord other) {
        // implement your custom logic here, returning -1, 0, or 1
    }
}
```

Once you do that, you can sort them using the default sorter.

Comment: Ok great thanks.  In doing a little further reasearch I may want to implement some classes that implement IComparer<T> since I have different ways I woukld like to sort. Thanks for getting me started here!

Comment: No prob. Yep, `IComparer` does give you a little more flexibility, so that may work out best for you.